# Django admin custom action request

Tags: django, http

I've written a custom action and through model permissions have granted these to 2 users.

But now I only want one of them to run it at any one time. So was thinking whenever they select the `actionbox` and press the action button, it checks if a `request.POST` is already being made.

So my question is can I interrogate if there any other `HTTP` requests made before it takes the user to the intermediary page and display a message? But without having to mine the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

To take a step back, I think what you're really asking is how do you share data across entrypoints to your application.  e.g. if you only wanted 1 person to be able to trigger an action on a button at a time.

One strategy for doing this is to take some deployment-wide accessible datastore (like a cache or a message queue that ALL instances of your deployment have access to) and put in a message there that acts like a lock.  This would rely on that datastore to support atomic reads and writes.  Within Django, something like redis or memcached work well for this purpose (especially if you're using it as your cache backend.)

You might have something that looks like this (Example taken from the celery docs):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.core.cache import cache
from contextlib import contextmanager

LOCK_EXPIRE = 600 # Let the lock timeout in case your code crashes.

@contextmanager
def memcache_lock(lock_id):
    timeout_at = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=LOCK_EXPIRE)
    # cache.add fails if the key already exists
    status = cache.add(lock_id, 'locked', LOCK_EXPIRE)
    try:
        yield status
    finally:
        if datetime.now() < timeout_at and status:
            # don't release the lock if we exceeded the timeout
            # to lessen the chance of releasing an expired lock
            # owned by someone else
            # also don't release the lock if we didn't acquire it
            cache.delete(lock_id)


def my_custom_action(self, *args, **kwargs):
    lock_id = "my-custom-action-lock"
    with memcache_lock(lock_id) as acquired:
        if acquired:
            return do_stuff()
        else:  
            do_something_else_if_someone_is_already_doing_stuff()
            return
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Was trying to avoid using a message broker of sorts. We’re using oracle as our backend so could consider adding some lock attribute that’s released. However should i consider your example snippet as an alternative?

Comment: hi again ill try out the code above and post back, many thanks